# Kubelet is in running state but kubectl is giving connection to the server refused error

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Kubernetes cluster was working fine earlier,  Started getting issues running kubectl commands after restarting the master node (1.0.0.0). When I run `kubectl get nodes` command I am getting below error.

```
# kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server 1.0.0.0:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

When I connect to master node which is (`1.0.0.0`), the port 6443 is not open to accept connections. `netstat -lntp|grep 6443` Gives no output.
Kubelet service is in running state, the output of `systemctl status kubelet` doesn't show anything suspecious.

Tried restarting kubelet service but no luck. Also tried `swapoff -a` before restarting kubelet service.

Am I missing any other service which accepts connections on 6443 port? or is it the job of kubelet but failing to do so? Please help.

Note: Masked my IP address to 1.0.0.0, actual IP is different. Using only Centos every where.

Answer (score 1):

**Check below possible solutions :**

First review the logs of `journalctl -xeu` kubelet output, check if the `error while dialing dial unix /var/run/cri-dockerd.sock: connect: no such file or directory` then you restart and enable **cri-dockerd services** like below :

```
sudo systemctl enable cri-dockerd.service
sudo systemctl restart cri-dockerd.service then
sudo systemctl start kubelet
```

It may work for you,please go through [github link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/9375) for more info.

**1**)The Kubeconfig environmental variable is probably not set.
`export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` or `$HOME/.kube/config`

**2**)The user’s $HOME directory has `no .kube/config` file.
If you don’t have a .kube or config file

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf HOME/.kube/config sudo chown (id -u):$(id -g) 
$HOME/.kube/config
```

Alternatively you can also export KUBECONFIG variable like this:

```
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
```

**3**)The server/port configured in the config file above is wrong.
Is it the same as the IP/hostname of the master server? if not did you copy it? You might want to fix that.

By the way you can get the hostname by issueing the hostname command on your cli. or
ifconfig for the ip.

**4**)Docker service may be down, hence the kubeapi pod isn’t running

```
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl start kubelet
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown (id -u):(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

**5**)Kubelet service may be down. This may be due to the fact that swap is enabled:

- sudo -i
- swapoff -a
- exit
- strace -eopenat kubectl version

and you can type kubectl get nodes again as shown in the below.

[image]

**6**)May be another cause **‘disk space’:**

Check **`“df -h”`**, no overlay or shm (mounted on **`/var/lib/docker…`**) was listed, until you increased the free disk space.

**7**)Follow the below similar process to resolve your issue

**master**

kubeadm reset
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.211.40 --
kubernetes-version=v1.18.0

```
    kubeadm join 192.168.211.40:6443 --token s7apx1.mlxn2jkid6n99fr0 \
        --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:2fa9da39110d02efaf4f8781aa50dd25cce9be524618dc7ab91a53e81c5c22f8 

    $ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
    $ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
    $ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

**node1**

```
$ kubeadm reset
$ kubeadm join 192.168.211.40:6443 --token s7apx1.mlxn2jkid6n99fr0 \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:2fa9da39110d02efaf4f8781aa50dd25cce9be524618dc7ab91a53e81c5c22f8
```

**node2**

```
$ kubeadm reset
$ kubeadm join 192.168.211.40:6443 --token s7apx1.mlxn2jkid6n99fr0 \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:2fa9da39110d02efaf4f8781aa50dd25cce9be524618dc7ab91a53e81c5c22f8
```

**master**

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
master   Ready    master   5m18s   v1.18.6
node1    Ready    <none>   81s     v1.18.6
node2    Ready    <none>   43s     v1.18.6
$ scp /root/.kube/config root@192.168.211.41:/root/.kube/config
$ scp /root/.kube/config root@192.168.211.42:/root/.kube/config
```

**8**)Please try this if you still have the issue :

iptables may cause issues after you reboot your instance.

```
sudo su
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT ALL
iptables -F
```

Also refer to This [document describes steps to troubleshoot kubectl error](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/troubleshooting-kubectl-error-the-connection-to-the-server-x-x-x-x6443-was-refused-did-you-specify-the-right-host-or-port/) for more information.

Also check this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571312/port-6443-connection-refused-when-setting-up-kubernetes) for more information.